# How to judge the dofile is done correctly in lua

Tags: lua

How can I know if `dofile` is done correctly. I call do file in pcall. I found it can't return when i give a nil parameter.

```
dofile(nil)
```

Comment: You should add some code illustrating the problem, and the specific behaviour that you want the solution to provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dofile` does not work in protected mode, when it encounters error, the error is propagated to its caller.

However, your example is a different story:

```
dofile(nil)
```

The argument of `dofile` (the file name) is optional, when it's called without arguments (or, in your case, called with `nil`), it executes the contents from `stdin`. Try it in the interpreter, and you will see.

Comment: How can I prevent from that things happen

Comment: @Samuel You mean: to prevent from propagating the error? Use `pcall` as your question says.

Comment: I do 'print(pcall(dofile(nil)))'. That can't return

Comment: Replace `dofile` with a new version: `local old_dofile = dofile; dofile = function(file) if file == nil then error("dofile called with nil") end return old_dofile(file) end`

Comment: @Samuel As I said in the answer, `dofile(nil)` executes the contents from the standard input, it doesn't return because it's still expecting input. Try input some code and press the `EOF` key (Ctrl + D in Unix or Ctrl + Z in Windows)

Comment: I find `dofile` just raise an error instaed of returning it. I want to handle the error. So I use loadfile. But I found it's wrong. `local ok, msg = pcall(local f=loadfile('sd.lua')) ; f()`

Comment: @Samuel `localfile` is different, it doesn't raise the error, try `local f = assert(loadfile('sd.lua')); f()`

Comment: But I want to catch the error. Now the only way i know is `pcall`

Comment: @Samuel Please, take the time to look up the functions used in [the Lua documentation](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/index.html#contents). `loadfile` does not raise syntax errors, while `dofile` does.